# Grab row of data from SQL Server given value of one cell in a column in that row--Visual Basic

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I checked whether a value exists

```
Dim connectionString = [connection string ]

Using exist As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE WorkEmail = @WorkEmail", exist)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkEmail", DataObjects.Contacts.ElectronicAddress.Email)

    If cmd.ExecuteScalar > 0 Then
        //return row so that I can grab values from it, given column names
```

How would I go about doing that commented section on the last line?

Answer (score 0):

You should execute your command and then check if it returned any rows.

See [Retrieving Data Using a Data Reader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

An excerpt slightly tweaked for your use case:

```
Private Sub HasRows(ByVal connection As SqlConnection)
    Using connection
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE WorkEmail = @WorkEmail", connection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkEmail", DataObjects.Contacts.ElectronicAddress.Email)
            connection.Open()

            Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                    REM Your code to pull the data you want from the returned data goes here
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

In the future try looking through the Microsoft Documents. You will usually find what you need there.